# Div field not updating

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am not sure why this field is not updating with the correct number.  It is worth noting that for some reason that any number <1 is rounding in the alert() function.  I think all the numbers are just getting rounded down but I don't know another method to get the value that won't do that? Any suggestions?

actual value = 0.03

```
var citrullineChoice = document.getElementById("citrulline").getElementsByClassName("on")[0].value;
```

alert returns 0

actual value = 0.03

```
var tyrosineChoice = document.getElementById("tyrosine").getElementsByClassName("on")[0].value;
```

alert returns 1

[Code Here](http://codepen.io/garvdaddy/pen/pEpVAQ?editors=1010)

Comment: In your code example you're using jQuery. Is there any reason you're not using jQuery to get the value?

Comment: @Kolby, speed and performance enthusiasts ;). OP could use SizzleJS engine.

Comment: @Kolby mostly because i only know javascript. that code was just a little excerpt from my javascript so maybe im doing something wrong here...

Comment: @NickGarver, a side note: you're loading an 82Kb library into your app, either make use of it or don't load it. Nothing wrong with using Vanilla JavaScript, you don't need jQuery here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fix for what you want: http://codepen.io/emiyake/pen/bwKRQP

I am passing the value to the function, instead of adding it as an attribute value to your element.

```
<li id="caffeinetwo" class="off" onclick="changeClass(this, 0.03)">250</li>
```

Also changed your changeClass a bit, so you won't need to change it if you want to add or remove an option in your creation bar.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much.  I was trying to figure out a cleaner way to do this and wow, this was a great update.  I am going to have to keep track of these numbers in a database so this helps me more than you know.

Answer (score 1):

You try use the parseFloat() method, because javascript may be trying to add the value to an int.

```
var tyrosineChoice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("tyrosine").getElementsByClassName("on")[0].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.innerText` instead of `.value` - you don't have any input elements.

jQuery library is not added to your example, there is a console error:

> pen.js:191 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

on

```
$("#perServing").html("$" + perServing);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.getAttribute('value')` instead of `.value`

```
var citrullineChoice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("citrulline").getElementsByClassName("on")[0].getAttribute('value'));
```

Here your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgZqvO)